# I want to make a loop checking for pairs VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a project involving checking for pairs in a column. I´m a beginner so I tried

```
If a = b Then
    Par = Par + 1
End If
If a = c Then
    Par = Par + 1
End If
If a = d Then
    Par = Par + 1
End If
```

etc etc but if I want this to work I´ll have to repeat this code 36 times...

Is there an easy loop for this?

Comment: a,b,c,d.. are the columns on your sheet? So.. columns 1,2,3,4...?

Comment: Please give proper example data or a screenshot of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way that might meet your needs.

Imagine a simple table in range `A1:B5`

```
   A   B
1  aa  aa
2  cc  bb
3  ee  cc
4  gg  dd
5  hh  ee
```

Here we have three pairs `aa & aa, cc & cc, ee & ee`.

This formula will count the number of pairs:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1:A5,B1:B5)) // = 3
```